# Chrome Push Notification Updating Service-Worker.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification

I am using Google Chrome Push Notification in my site.
Currently I have more than 1,00,000 subscribed users.

**I'm facing this following issue.**

- My users started using the notifications.
- I need to change the logic of the service-worker but could not able update it.
- I have not given any cache based installation with my previous Service-Wroker.js
- I have not used any fetch event with the previous Service-Worker.js

**Changes done in new Service-Worker.js** 
- Landing URL **(clickUrl)** variable is added into the **self.addEventListener** function

**My Existing Service-Wroker.js**

```
'use strict';

var port;
var pushMessage;

var clickUrl;
var imgUrl;

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

    var obj      = event.data;
    pushMessage  = event.data ? event.data.text() : '';
    var pushData = pushMessage.split('####');

    clickUrl = pushData[2];
    imgUrl   = pushData[1];
    if (port) {
        port.postMessage(pushMessage);
    }

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(pushData[3], {
        requireInteraction: true,
        body: pushData[0],
        icon: pushData[1]
    }));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    if (Notification.prototype.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
        event.notification.close();
        event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(clickUrl));
    }
});

self.onmessage = function(e) {
    port = e.ports[0];
    if (pushMessage) {
        port.postMessage(pushMessage);
    }
};
```

**The new / updated Service-Worker.js [Changes I need to update / implement]**

```
'use strict';

var port;
var pushMessage;

var clickUrl;
var imgUrl;

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {

    var obj      = event.data;
    pushMessage  = event.data ? event.data.text() : '';
    var pushData = pushMessage.split('####');

    clickUrl = pushData[2];
    imgUrl   = pushData[1];
    if (port) {
        port.postMessage(pushMessage);
    }

    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(pushData[3], {
        requireInteraction: true,
        body: pushData[0],
        icon: pushData[1],
        data:{
            url : clickUrl
        }
    }));
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    var landingUrl = event.notification.data.url;
    if (Notification.prototype.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
        event.notification.close();
        event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(landingUrl));
    }
});

self.onmessage = function(e) {
    port = e.ports[0];
    if (pushMessage) {
        port.postMessage(pushMessage);
    }
};

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Installed version', version);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('my-cache').then(function(cache) {
            // Important to `return` the promise here to have `skipWaiting()`
            // fire after the cache has been updated.
            return cache.addAll([/* file1.jpg, file2.png, ... */]);
        }).then(function() {
            // `skipWaiting()` forces the waiting ServiceWorker to become the
            // active ServiceWorker, triggering the `onactivate` event.
            // Together with `Clients.claim()` this allows a worker to take effect
            // immediately in the client(s).
            return self.skipWaiting();
        })
    );
});

// Activate event
// Be sure to call self.clients.claim()
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    // `claim()` sets this worker as the active worker for all clients that
    // match the workers scope and triggers an `oncontrollerchange` event for
    // the clients.
    return self.clients.claim();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> An update is triggered:
>
> - On navigation to an in-scope page.
> - On functional events such as push and sync, unless there's been an update check within the previous 24 hours.
> - On calling .register() only if the service worker URL has changed.

more here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle